# ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: None

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, valueerror

I am writing a code that will filter values in a csv file and write relevant rows to one file, accepted but not desired rows to another and error files to a third file.

This is what I've writen:

```
#variables
doc = '/lab01/Projects/Lords_Projects/mna_exons.csv'
save = '/lab01/Projects/Lords_Projects/mna_exac.csv'
other = '/lab01/Projects/Lords_Projects/mna_alt.csv'
error = '/lab01/Projects/Lords_Projects/mna_error.csv'
seek = 'ExAC_ALL'
comp = .05

#script
import csv

#open
read = open(doc, 'rb')
write = open(save, 'wb')
dif = open(other, 'wb')
mis = open(error, 'wb')

#text conversion
reader = csv.DictReader(read, delimiter=',')
copy = csv.DictWriter(write, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
alt = csv.DictWriter(dif, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
er = csv.DictWriter(mis, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)

#headers
head = {}
for n in reader.fieldnames:
  head[n] = n
copy.writerow(head)
alt.writerow(head)
er.writerow(head)

#sorting
for row in reader:
  try:
    if float(row[seek]) < comp and float(row[seek]) > -comp:
      copy.writerow(row)
    elif float(row[seek]) >= comp or float(row[seek]) <= -comp:
      alt.writerow(row)
  except:
    try:
      if row[seek] == 'N/A':
        copy.writerow(row)
    except:
      prob = csv.writer(write, delimiter='\t')
      er.writerow(row)
      prob.writerow("Value Not Float\n")
#Close
read.close()
write.close()
dif.close()
mis.close()

#Error Check
if 'Value Not Float\n' in open(save, 'r').read():
  print('Error')
open(save, 'r').close()
```

When I run it, it gives me this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "csv_cond_filter.py", line 45, in 
>      er.writerow(row)
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/csv.py", line 152, in writerow
>      return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
>      + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
>   ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: None

To test to see what specifically might be wrong, I made the error line a comment and ran the script again. It did not give me an error message, nor did it print the error value I specified it to write if it could not classify the segment, so I suspect it is a syntax error, but I'm new to python, and I don't know enough about the csv module or DictWriter.

Comment: Can we get samples of the files that cause the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to display the contents of the row: replace

```
er.writerow(row)
```

with

```
try:
    er.writerow(row)
except Exception as exc:
    exc.args += (row,)
    raise
```